# How do I add a plot to an animated list of images in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I took the following piece of code from [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/gallery/animation/dynamic_image2.html). After `plt.imshow()` I want to draw a red dot that is on a different position for each "frame".

How do I use `plt.plot()` that is unique to its `plt.imshow()`?

The code below keeps the previously drawn red dots from the previous "frames".

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()


def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
# ims is a list of lists, each row is a list of artists to draw in the
# current frame; here we are just animating one artist, the image, in
# each frame
ims = []
for i in range(60):
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)

    # my added code here
    plt.plot(pos_x, pos_y, 'ro') # pos_x, pos_y change on every iteration

    ims.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

# ani.save('dynamic_images.mp4')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the `Line2D` object that is created by `plot` in the list of animated objects.

```
line, = plt.plot(pos_x, pos_y, 'ro')

ims.append([im, line])
```